# Need simplified formula of probability equation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have RV $x$ which is function of independent continuous RVs $x_1$ and $x_2$. After some manipulations, I came up with an expression for the outage probability of $x$ as 
$$P_\text{out}(y)=\Pr(x\leq y)=\Pr(x_1\leq y)+\Pr(x_1>y)\Pr(x_2\leq y\mid x_1>y).$$
Since I need to evaluate this, I want to write this one in integral forms. Can someone give me some hints?

Ex: There are two connected links where 1st link RV is $x_1$ and 2nd link RV is $x_2$. The whole link is in outage i) if $x_1\leq y$ or ii) if $x_1>y$ but $x_2\leq y$.

Comment: I am suspicious of a sum of probabilities conditional on different events.  Can you explain how you got this? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I have revised the explanation, and made a correlation.

Comment: Is 2nd term equivalent to $\Pr(x_2\leq y; x_1>y)$?